# /bin/sh: /Users/{userName}/Desktop/{name}/Test No such file or directory (React Native Ios build issue in Mac book)

Tags: ios, reactjs, command-line-interface

Project is in **React Native Cli**.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCJjy.jpg)

1. RN version : 0.68.0
2. Mac book modal : 11.67
3. react version : 17.~.~
4. XCode version : 13.1

this error occur on local run of react native cli project.

**Note : I already check through by deleting pod folder and reinstall it. but didn't work. Also test with by with and without comment code of flipper in pod file**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your main folder name it should not include spaces. After doing this try building your app again.